# If this does not qualify as an answer, then how else would the question be answered?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, deleted-answers, convert-to-comment

A moderator deleted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23194497/100297):

```
You cannot yield two blocks in a method.

But you can take two procs.

    def by_two(n, a, pr1, pr2)
      pr1.call(n)
      pr2.call(a)
    end
    by_two(10, 300, proc1, proc2)
```

to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194414) and converted it into a comment. How could the question have been answered without being deleted?

Comment: I think the more puzzling question is why the answer got flagged. Moderators are community experts, not Ruby experts, but the person who flagged the answer obviously has some sort of interest in Ruby, otherwise she wouldn't have read the question and answer in the first place. And the answer is so *obviously* correct to anyone with even the slightest knowledge of Ruby that I simply don't understand how someone could flag it.

Comment: In the meantime, your post has been undeleted.

Comment: Glad to know that.

Comment: I see so many good answers been either wrongly flagged or deleted that I simply do not know if those "expert" is actually experts at all and how did they get so many points that one should spent day by day to opening and answering questions without launch break -- even then it would not be enough..

Comment: @AllBlond there are a lot of people here, who answered questions like [how to find substring in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1789952/1090562), or other simple oneliners which could be found by anyone reading documentation.

Comment: I am not talking about sub string and strings. friend of mine use to have here account which was flagged for reason I still do not know.And I looked through his questions and some of his answers he gave, maybe because not to many people even heard about CMS he was talking and asking questions. So what, if you did not heard about something is that a good reason to flag someone? And by the way if Salvador would be alive he would never ask that kind of questions.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, it may have got flagged var one of the review queue by someone that does not know ruby.

Comment: @AllBlond Don't you mean your old account not your friends? [stackoverflow.com dead or just to much to handle?](http://allblond.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/stackoverflowcom-dead-or-just-to-much.html). May be it's more to do with the way you ask questions, that is if your answers and comments are anything to go by.

Answer (score 22):

Bohemian must've missed that you *edited* your post after it was flagged by someone as not an answer. An honest mistake.

Simply flag your post, use 'other' and ask for it to be undeleted (nicely). Explain that your answer was initially just one sentence but has since been edited to be a full answer.

Comment: My edit does not affect its status as an answer. The answer was given in the original post. The edit was additional information.

Comment: @sawa: *Someone* thought it was not an answer but a comment and flagged it as such; Bohemian would not have acted on your post without such a flag. Explaining that you edited the post helps moderators when assessing the situation.

Comment: I appreciate your information regarding what happened. I am not doubting that. But I should not need to, and will not, explain that to the moderators.

Comment: Was it deleted before you finished editing or something weird like that?

Comment: @OneKitten: no, it was deleted 13 minutes after the last edit. That edit was made after slightly over 5 minutes from posting the initial revision.

Comment: If he had the answer list open prior to the edit in the mod tools, he very well could have been looking at the older version.  Tough one, either way.  The question is kinda NARQ as "you can't do that" is the real answer :/

Comment: @sawa It's probably an honest mistake. Just point it out and have it undeleted (if a mod doesn't pick it up here). Mods are (mostly) humans who do on occasion fat finger a post. And please stop your nonsense comments on the question and other answers to it that only relate to what happened to you and the "dangers" this might spell for their authors as well.

Comment: If its an honest mistake let @Bohemian clarify it. I think sawa wants to here from him.

Comment: @Satpal: This isn't about specific moderators. He could be away and / or unaware of this post. Pinging him in a comment doesn't actually *work*, btw.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  I've been super-pinged on a post I've moderated recently, so AFAIK, they still work.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: What, here on Meta, if I name a moderator that has *not* participated anywhere on this page, they will be pinged?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Tried three different ones for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Ooooh, I *so* found a new toy!

Comment: @MartijnPieters We... uhhh... also get auto flags for abusers of Super Pings. Yeah, that's it...

Comment: @AndrewBarber: OOoooh, really? Let me try to find the triggers for that now!

Comment: @MartijnPieters And, uhh... it comes with an auto-suspension that moderators can't cancel. Oh, and Community Managers aren't likely to, either. Yeah, that's it...

Comment: @AndrewBarber: You do know the scientist in me **so** wants to test that hypothesis, and damn the consequences, right?

Comment: Oh. In that case, I'm just kidding. And super pings don't work, anyway. @GeorgeStocker and I were just pulling your chain. Try it a couple times and see! (Note to George: Be sure to pretend you don't see Martijn's SPs!)

Comment: /me goes off to ping other moderators other than Andrew and George. So what if *some* of them get annoyed, I'll just tell them that Andrew told him it wouldn't work..